# Sharepoint 2013 App upgrade issue

Tags: deployment, updates, sharepoint-2013

I met an annoying problem when i try to upgrade my new version app 1.0.0.1 to my sharepoint 2013 server.

The detail steps I did,

1, Create a development site in sp 2013.

2, Create a sharepoint-host app project in visualstudio.

3, using "deploy" to deploy the app to sp2013.

4, Now the version number is 1.0.0.0, and everything looks good.

5, I made some changes and set a new version number at AppManifest.xml,1.0.0.1.

6, using

```
$spapp = Import-SPAppPackage -Path .\DevCore.AppCalendar.app -Site [http://sp-ss2013/sites/testapp] -Source ([microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spappsource]::ObjectModel)
$instance = Get-SPAppInstance -AppInstanceId 4c472c85-2759-489f-8435-c6cc7b11eb91 -Site [http://sp-ss2013/sites/testapp]
Update-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance -App $spapp
```

to update the `appinstance`.

7, after the update process has been done, check the app detail, it is the new version number.

8, **But all stuff in app look the same, the change doest work at all**

I tried iisrest but it turns out the same result.

Really need help, otherwise I have to reinstall the app......

/Dong

Comment: I figured out my own, a bit tricky, add ReplaceContent="TRUE" at element,xml saves my ass